# time consumed by win32 console

Tags: c++

I have written my code in c++2012 in windows 7 with win32 and console for seeing the result of my program. Because my program must be competitive by passing the time (time is being measured for every step of solution), I think that in console some extra time is consumed to write the output data.
My question is that: Is my proposition true and if true how do I change my c++ project type ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that concole writing takes comparatively long time. 
But why do you want to change your project type?

Just write the data to some file, like:

```
your_prog >results.txt
```

Then the output goes to `results.txt` and can be viewed later.

Comment: How do I disable the console while my project type is win32console?

Comment: @MehdiTanhatalab - did you understand the above? `your_prog >results.txt`

Comment: @ Ingo. Yes I understood. I had a file report to show the output in txt file before your guidance. But my problem is that in my project type after running the program win32 come up (I send no report to console) and I think this is time consuming too. I want to have not the console at all. Please help me to disable the console not ever to raise.

Comment: @MehdiTanhatalab  Ahh, now I understand - you're asking a question about some tool you use. Sorry, can't help you there, am here to help solve programming problems.

Comment: @ Ingo. No i do not want a tool to disable console window. I want to know that is there any code or trick in c++ to obstacle popping up the console while project is of win32console application type.

Comment: @MehdiTanhatalab No. It is your editor (IDE?) that defines "project types" and the like and  decides to show a console when you start your program through it. Consult your IDE documentation for how to change this. Perhaps changing the "project type" is the right thing.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, writing the output on the console can significantly impact performance. However, simply changing console output to file output should do the trick; the fact that the console appears on the screen is irrelevant, so changing project type is unnecessary.